# Can a pip install have detrimental effects to your computer?

Tags: python, pip

Recently, I have been exploring github and went on an install spree using "pip install -r requirements.txt". Today, I came across one that required my antivirus to give permission. Felt suspicious, but I installed it anyway. `pip install git+https://github.com/something`

Usually, command "python something.py" would execute program and produce results. This particular program would instead run with its own command, even after I deleted the cloned source files.

Could something malicious have gotten into my computer? It wanted access to python/lib/packages and /scripts and I granted it. Would pip uninstall have gotten rid of it safely?

Comment: This question is *rather vaguely worded*. I gave you a generic answer, I can't say anything about a `something` project on github or details as to what command was run after you deleted the cloned source files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `pip install` will execute remote code with your user access; anything could have happened that you as a user can do on your computer without admin access.

Now, *usually* the `setup.py` file of a project does nothing more than just install the project files into your Python `site-packages` dir (and optionally to `bin/` or `Scripts/`, depending on your OS), but the code *could* do anything, really.

Always take a look over the `setup.py` of a project you download; you should find nothing more than a `setup()` call and some imports and perhaps some platform-detection to alter the settings passed to the `setup()` function.

If your AV solution only flagged access to `lib/site-packages` and `Scripts`, you should be fine. Provided the library you installed doesn't carry any malicious trojan, of course. Again, with the code publicly visible on GitHub, you should be able to give it at least a cursory check, right?

Comment: It was my mistake to think that only kind programmers are on github. These guys are running a discord channel as well. With the message in readme.mi: "join us if you have problems with setup."When you get on, they will ask you to run the command again, I believe that's when they update their github files to bad ones for a brief moment, so that they replace what's downloaded to your computer.

Comment: @Hodor: and the history on GitHub would reflect that change. They can do it, but not without notice.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you stick to the well known packages used and reviewed by many people, you should be safe and the package install script will not do any harm.

However, you should watch out for typos. It is really easy to compromise the `pip` central repository with packages that can do anything on your computer...

See this interesting article for more details: http://incolumitas.com/2016/06/08/typosquatting-package-managers/

Comment: I feel like I must format my computer, since anything could have happened. Even then, will formatting get rid of all doubts?